# transpose pyspark df and get back a pyspark df

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm trying to transpose an object type data frame and want to get back a data frame object (after it's been transposed):

[image]

and transpose into this:

[image]

I need the transposed object to remain a spark data frame.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this out. you can use `groupby` and `pivot`. Please note i renamed `name` column because it was ambiguous to the dataframe once the `name` values are pivoted

```
    df.show()

    # +------------+-----+
    # |        name|value|
    # +------------+-----+
    # |        Name|  str|
    # |lastActivity| date|
    # |          id|  str|
    # +------------+-----+

    df1 = df.withColumnRenamed("name", "name_val").groupBy("name_val").pivot("name_val").agg(F.first("value"))

    df1.show()

    # +------------+----+----+------------+
    # |    name_val|Name|  id|lastActivity|
    # +------------+----+----+------------+
    # |        Name| str|null|        null|
    # |          id|null| str|        null|
    # |lastActivity|null|null|        date|
    # +------------+----+----+------------+

    df1.select(*[F.first(column,ignorenulls=True).alias(column) for column in df1.columns if column not in 'name_val']).show()


    # 
    # +----+---+------------+
    # |Name| id|lastActivity|
    # +----+---+------------+
    # | str|str|        date|
    # +----+---+------------+
```